# colour part of the output from a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors

One cell has a formula:

```
=CONCAT("a","b")
```

in which "a" is a character string but "b" is in reality a value from another function.

I was asked to colour "b" red and keep "a" black. How do I do this?

Comment: I can't be done

Comment: This is such an strange request to me, I would really like to hear the (hopefully hilarious) back story on it...

Comment: Formula is only available for values but not format. You should use code to get the result.

Comment: Put _a_ in one cell and _b_ in another.  To do it in one cell you'd need code to replace the formula with the actual value and then colour the values.  You'd then need to put the formula back whenever you wanted to update the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly enough it's a question for an excel exam. All but this one were reasonable :/.